# How can I fix this example so that it works after the first or second subclass?

Tags: javascript

In this example, I'm trying to create a Class template, then using that to create a base 'class', and so on and so forth.

It all works until I get to NewStudent. I get a type error 'object is not a function'.

```
var Class = function(options) {
    var newClass = function(options) {
        $.extend(this, options);
    };

    if (options) {
        $.extend(newClass, options);
    }

    newClass.prototype = newClass;
    newClass.prototype.constructor = newClass;
    return newClass;
};

var Person = new Class();
Person.prototype.speak = function() {alert(this.name + ', ' + this.type);}


var Student = new Person({name: 'Student', type: 'Student'});
Student.speak();

var NewStudent = new Student({name: 'NewStudent'});
NewStudent.speak();
```

If I change:

```
var newClass = function(options) {
    $.extend(this, options);
};
```

to:

```
var newClass = function(options) {
    $.extend(this, options);
    return newClass;
};
```

It it executes the speak call, but the name is blank, and the type is unidentified.

I'm using jquery for the $.extend method.

How can I improve this so it works? I'm trying to do something similar to the way Mootools does their Class, except I want to create my own barebone version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing objects with functions.

The Person variable is a function, but the Student variable is an ordinary object, so you can't "new" it.

You'll have to create a separate function to create derived classes. I reworked your example a bit, and came up with this:

```
Class = function(ParentClass, options) {

    if (ParentClass && typeof(ParentClass) != 'function') {
      options = ParentClass;
      ParentClass = undefined;
    }

    var ctr = function(objOptions) {
      $.extend(this,objOptions);
    };

    if (typeof(ParentClass) == 'function') {
      ctr.prototype = new ParentClass();
    }

    $.extend(ctr.prototype,options);

    ctr.Derive = function(options) { return new Class(ctr,options); };

    return ctr;
};
```

Then you can do what you intended:

```
var Person = new Class({ speak: function() {alert(this.name + ', ' + this.type);} });
var Student = Person.Derive({type: 'Student'});
var NewStudent = Student.Derive({type:"NewStudent"});

var student = new Student({name: 'student'});
student.speak();

var newStudent = new NewStudent({name: 'newStudent'});
newStudent.speak();
```

The code above can be executed here: http://jsbin.com/unetox/6

Comment: So calling new on a function returns an object. I'm going to try and automate it one more level, to avoid calling Class.create (if it's possible). Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't expect "new Student()" to create a new class for you and at the same time allow you to create a new object of type "Student". I don't think you can make it a lot easier than what I've shown though.

Comment: I made a small change making it simpler to use.

Comment: Yeah, I responded too soon. I've thought about it for a bit more and realized I was thinking about the problem the wrong way. Now I understand more clearly, and also understand the reason the Class structure in Mootools has an Implements/Extends option.